# ArcGIS Pro will not update datasource path change

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, file-path

I have many layers in a aprx file that need to have the path updated. I need to remove part of the string "UTARC." from the datasource path.
Through Catalag View on ArcGIS Pro, when I type the new path, a green horizontal bar shows in the left side of the new path. Then  when I click on "APPLY" ArcGIS Pro does not change the path!
It only works if I go through Properties on the layer and change it manually.

I tried with a Python script and it does not work either. The script runs with no error but no change is made.

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"projectpath")
aprx.updateConnectionProperties("UTARC."," ")
aprx.saveACopy(r"projectpath\new.aprx")
```

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that you're not replacing correctly, you're replacing 'UTARC.' with ' ' (a space). I'm guessing you might want this instead:

aprx.updateConnectionProperties("UTARC.","")

That should completely remove 'UTARC.' and not add a space.